# Is there a way to run "tsc -watch" and "npm start" at the same time, with a click of a button/ shortcut on VSCode?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code, npm-start

I am new to node.js and typescript, and I was wondering whether there is any way to run those two commands at the same time with the click of a button or command on visual studio code.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can execute a command via a click by clicking on the "npm scripts" tab shown on your left hand side (default)

[image: npm scripts]

If you want to execute multiple commands in single click you have to use something like [concurrently](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently)

open you package.json and edit script

```
"script" : {
  "my-script": "concurrently \"tsc-watch\" \"npm start\""
}
```